# Creating custom CRS in QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, qgis-3

I am trying to define a custom CRS in QGIS 3.4 to work on some data in Central Asia. I want to use the `Albers Equal Area Conic` but change the parameters so that the transformation works best for my study area.

I first tried to go via "Settings" --> "Custom CRS". I defined the name and the `+proj`string as `+proj=aea +lat_1=21 +lat_2=49 +lat_0=37 +lon_0=87 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`. But when I click "Ok", nothing happens.

I don't get an error message or any feedback, there's just no response. (I tried QGIS 3.10 as well, but the same problem occurred.) This looks like a bug to me or is there something I missed?

If this cannot be reproduced, I could also go the Python way, but I'm not so familiar with that. I've read through some documentation and found the following pieces of code but I'm not sure if they are in the right order or if something is missing:

```py
my_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
my_crs.createFromProj4("+proj=aea +lat_1=21 +lat_2=49 +lat_0=37 +lon_0=87 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
my_crs.saveAsUserCrs("Albers_Central_Asia")
```

Comment: works for me in QGIS 3.4.6

Comment: Could you give me the detailed workflow for this, please? You first click the green "plus", then add name and proj-string and click "ok"? Because that way it does not work for me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. add new profile.
   : Settings -> User Profiles -> New profile
2. use new profile and try creating custom projections.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I hadn't even thought about that! Sometimes it can be so simple.

Comment: @color mint This worked for me, but why? Why do we have to do this? Why doesn't the "default" profile work?

Answer (score 4):

`Settings > Custom Projections > Green Plus`

Add name and parameters > OK

[image: Custom Projection in QGIS 3.4.6]

Creates a custom projection (in my case called USER:100030)

[image: custom projection USER:100030]

Comment: Thanks for the details! This is exactly how I've been doing it. So it seems to be a bug... Do you perchance also know how to write this in Python?

Comment: I installed QGIS under Linux and was able to create the CRS using your workflow. I still don't know what the problem was, though.

Comment: My example is Linux based too.  I've tried since on Windows with 3.6.3 version and it works just the same

Comment: Strange... However, now I'm stuck on trying to export the custom crs to Windows. I've tried to save a raster with this crs and open it on Windows, but there it appears to have no projection. Does this work for you? Or is there another way to export a projection?

Comment: You can do a direct edit of the .../share/proj/other.extra file to add custom projections

Comment: I know, this is slowly turning into another question, but what would this edit look like? I have tried giving a custom ID and the proj-string like this: 
<901000> +proj=aea +lat_1=25 +lat_2=50 +lat_0=37 +lon_0=87 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs <>
But when I search in QGIS for the ID nothing is found...

Comment: OK, method works for other applications, but perhaps QGIS doesn't read them :(   A quick search shows that QGIS stores it's custom projections in a sqlite database, so I assume a direct edit of that db would work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I stumbled about this before but I've not worked with SQL and the QGIS-website says not to mess around with this database. Do you know a safe way to do this?