# Creating an oblique Mercator projection using proj and QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-processing, proj, oblique-mercator

I am trying to create a coordinate system within QGIS that's aligned with a great circle between two points.

The points defining the great circle are (-44.0597,168.7192) and (-42.7365,171.4428) and, ideally, I'd like the first of these to be correspond to the origin of the new system. From what I can tell from proj.org, the following definition should work:

```
+proj=omerc +lat_0=-44.0597 +lonc=168.7192 +lat_1=-44.0597 +lon_1=168.7192 +lat_2=-42.7365 +lon_2=171.4428 +units=km
```

However, when I test this, I'm told that (-44.0597,168.7192) maps to (0,0) [correct] whereas (-42.7365,171.4428) maps to (143,223) [incorrect].

This means that the new coordinate system has the origin I wanted but is not correctly aligned with the great circle. I've also tried specifying the new coordinate system using a center point and either +alpha=-33 or +gamma=-33 (since the great circle has an azimuth from the first point of about 57 deg.) but this isn't working correctly either.

I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing but after going round and round in circles, I'm at a loss to spot it. I'm using QGIS 3.10.2 and PROJ 6.3.0.

Comment: The `alpha` and `gamma` documentation is a bit confusing, but the essential thing is that the projections don't try to change 'north' unless you force it to change.   https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375104/can-i-visualize-a-spatial-movement-in-a-room-data-using-qgis/377710#377710

Comment: Also -- the `+lat_0=-44.0597 +lonc=168.7192` portion of your string is ignored if you do not have an alpha or gamma, and if you do have them, then the `+lat_1=-44.0597 +lon_1=168.7192 +lat_2=-42.7365 +lon_2=171.4428` portion of your string will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

For a skewed Proj4 `+proj=omerc` [oblique mercator](https://proj4.org/en/7.1/operations/projections/omerc.html) You should specify both `alpha` and `gamma`, otherwise proj assumes it should rotate both the mercator projection cylinder and the coordinate system on the cylinder to keep the +y direction pointing northwards.

For example:

```
+proj=omerc +lat_0=-44.0597 +lonc=168.7192 +alpha=-33 +gamma=0 +units=km
```

In WKT this is:

```
 % gdalsrsinfo "+proj=omerc +lat_0=-44.0597 +lonc=168.7192 +alpha=-33 +gamma=0 +units=km" -o wkt2       

PROJCRS["unknown",
    BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6326]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8901]]],
    CONVERSION["unknown",
        METHOD["Hotine Oblique Mercator (variant B)",
            ID["EPSG",9815]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of projection centre",-44.0597,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8811]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of projection centre",168.7192,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8812]],
        PARAMETER["Azimuth of initial line",-33,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8813]],
        PARAMETER["Angle from Rectified to Skew Grid",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8814]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor on initial line",1,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8815]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at projection centre",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["kilometre",1000],
            ID["EPSG",8816]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at projection centre",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["kilometre",1000],
            ID["EPSG",8817]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["kilometre",1000,
                ID["EPSG",9036]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["kilometre",1000,
                ID["EPSG",9036]]]]
```

Comment: It seems you are using some parameters from the proj omerc "two-point" method, and some parameters from its "one point and azimuth" method. Legit?

Comment: @DanJacobson: You are correct. The two point parameters are ignored if the Central Point and Azimuth, plus alpha or gamma options are included. If you don't have those three or four parameters, the central point and the azimuth are used.  I simplified the options.   Adding alpha and gamma to the OP's string switched it from using the 2 point to the central point method.