# Changing "Datum Transformation" is QGIS by PyQGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, qgis-3

Is it possible to change Datum Transformation in QGIS by QGIS?

[image]

For example add new Transformation or change actual.

Comment: Yes, try via `Settings > Custom Projections > Green Plus`, see this thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/341508/99589

Comment: OK, is it possible, but i need change projections by PyQGIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProject,
                       QgsDatumTransform,
                       QgsCoordinateTransformContext,
                       QgsCoordinateTransform,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)
from qgis import processing


class ExampleDatumTransformationAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExampleDatumTransformationAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return 'Example Datum Transformation'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('Transform Datum Projection')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Example scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'example'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example algorithm short description")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        pass
        
    def _clear_datum_settings(self):
        QgsProject.instance().setTransformContext(QgsCoordinateTransformContext().clear())
        
    def is_right_krovak_transformation(self, name, proj):
        if '(1)' in name and '570.8' in proj:
            self.feedback.pushInfo('[INFO]   Selected Transformation Datum: {0}'.format(proj))
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    def get_aviable_datum_transformations(self, source_epsg, dest_epsg):
        possible_transformation = QgsDatumTransform.operations(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(source_epsg), QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(dest_epsg), True)
        for tr in possible_transformation:
            if self.is_right_krovak_transformation(tr.name, tr.proj):
                return tr.proj
        
    def add_new_datum_transformation(self, settings, dest_epsg):     
        project = QgsProject.instance()
        context = QgsCoordinateTransformContext()
        for key, value in settings.items():
            context.addCoordinateOperation(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(key), QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(dest_epsg), value, True)
        project.setTransformContext(context)
        
    def add_new_datum_transformation_by_epsg(self, source_epsg_list, dest_epsg):
        settings = {}
        for source_epsg in source_epsg_list:
            settings[source_epsg] = self.get_aviable_datum_transformations(source_epsg, dest_epsg)
        self.add_new_datum_transformation(settings, dest_epsg)

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        self.feedback = feedback
        self.add_new_datum_transformation_by_epsg(["EPSG:3857", "EPSG:4326"], "EPSG:5514")
        
        return {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set datum transformations using the project [`QgsCoordinateTransformContext`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateTransformContext.html) accessible via `QgsProject.instance().transformContext()`

For Proj 5, you get existing list from

```py
QgsProject.instance().transformContext().sourceDestinationDatumTransforms()
```

For Proj 6+, you get existing list from

```py
QgsProject.instance().transformContext().coordinateOperations()
```

Then, use methods from `QgsCoordinateTransformContext` to add new datum transformations e.g `addSourceDestinationDatumTransform` (Proj 5) or `addCoordinateOperation` (Proj 6+)

To be able to get a generic solution depending of Proj version, you may want to use a condition with statement `QgsProjUtils.projVersionMajor()`

You may also look at related classes [`QgsDatumTransform`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsDatumTransform.html) (in particular to get "candidate" datums between projections) and [`QgsCoordinateTransform`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateTransform.html) (if interested by reprojecting coordinates using a datum transformation)